# Problem with diagonal collision response using PyGame

Tags: 2d, python, collision-resolution, pygame

So I have been having this problem for the last few days and it has me really frustrated. What I am trying to do is resolve collisions with custom hitboxes in PyGame and it looks something like this:

[image]

Everything works fine until I collide with something diagonaly, then I get a weird bug where the character suddenly teleports to the opposite axis side of what I am colliding with, like this:

https://gyazo.com/62c53cc4f3a944c317a951c0f8ae14ea

I have read a lot about this the last day and from what I have gathered this has to do with the fact that I don't resolve the x and y axis independently? maybe?

If I have a print("x") and print("y") statement in their respective code I get this when colliding with something on the "y" axis:

[image]

The bug seems to come from that somewhat random "x" in the middle there. The code resolves a collision as if the character was colliding with something on the "x" axis when in fact it was the "y" axis. It is worth nothing that this **ONLY** happens when diagonaly colliding with the last axis I check (y in this case). So I suppose that is my question really, why does this happen?

Here is my collision handling code:

```
def collide(self, direction):

    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, all_sprites_wall, False, rectconverter)
    if direction == "x":
        if hits:
            print("x")
            if self.vx > 0:
                hits[0].update()
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.left - self.rect.width - camera.camera.x
                self.hitboxrect.right = hits[0].hitboxrect.left
            if self.vx < 0:
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.right - self.rect.width + self.hitboxrect.width - camera.camera.x
                self.hitboxrect.left = hits[0].hitboxrect.right
            self.rect.x = self.x

    if direction == "y":
        if hits:
            print("y")
            if self.vy > 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.top - self.rect.height - camera.camera.y
                self.hitboxrect.bottom = hits[0].hitboxrect.top
            if self.vy < 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom - self.rect.height + self.hitboxrect.height - camera.camera.y
                self.hitboxrect.top = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom
            self.rect.y = self.y
```

And here is the players update function:

```
def update(self):
    self.move()

    self.hitboxrect.y = self.y + camera.camera.y + self.rect.height - self.hitboxrect.height
    self.rect.y = self.y
    self.collide("y")
    self.hitboxrect.x = self.x + camera.camera.x
    self.rect.x = self.x
    self.collide("x")
```

I think the problem lies somewhere in this code, but if you think otherwise feel free to say so and I would happily add more code!

Answer (score 1):

**Somehow I found the answer myself:**

The problem was in the fact that I was adding and subtracting the camera values, so by removing the cameras x and y values the bug disappeared. I am not really sure why this solved it to be honest but I will take it. Here is how the code looks now for anyone curious:

```
def collide(self, direction):
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self, all_sprites_wall, False, rectconverter)
    if direction == "x":
        if hits:
            print("x")
            if self.vx > 0:
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.left - self.rect.width
                self.hitboxrect.right = hits[0].hitboxrect.left
            if self.vx < 0:
                self.x = hits[0].hitboxrect.right - self.rect.width + self.hitboxrect.width
                self.hitboxrect.left = hits[0].hitboxrect.right
            self.rect.x = self.x
    if direction == "y":
        if hits:
            print("y")
            if self.vy > 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.top - self.rect.height
                self.hitboxrect.bottom = hits[0].hitboxrect.top
            if self.vy < 0:
                self.y = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom - self.rect.height + self.hitboxrect.height
                self.hitboxrect.top = hits[0].hitboxrect.bottom
            self.rect.y = self.y
```